# How do I attach a wrapper script to a binary?

Tags: bash, embed, executable

I have an executable say a.out. What I want to do is to attach a wrapper script to this executable which does a few things and then calls a.out. However, I would like to just have one file which I can distribute instead of two files. Any suggestions on how to do this?

I'm not terribly concerned about portability. Any solution that uses bash, perl or python is preferred but any scripting language would do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can append a.out to your wrapper script (after an `exit` in bash or `__END__` in Perl), which will extract it from itself to a new file, change its permissions  and run it.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Do few things before calling a.out"
/path/to/a.out 
echo "Done calling a.out"
```

Comment: Yeah but then I have to distribute a.out and wrapper.sh... I only want to be able to send one file wrapper+a.out.sh

Comment: `a.out` sits in your filesystem. You just call it using your wrapper script. You are in fact calling just one thing. What do you mean by 'distribute' or 'send' one file? send or distribute where ?